# Arduino for loop weird order

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I am starting out with Arduino and thus i'm writing a few scripts to try everything out. I have the idea to create a little LED second indicator. The binary digits of the current second are found in a python script and then send to the arduino which then displays the digits through turning on or off the LED's.

Everything is working fine except for that the LED's are turned on/off on the wrong order. For instance when the binary digits are 101101 the LED's show 011011. The last two digits are basically somehow processed by the first two LED's, whilst the rest work in normal order.

So to make sure it is understandable, when the LED's should be:

**on-on-on-on-off-off**

the LED's display:

**off-off-on-on-on-on**

The sent digits are correct when I print them out in the python script.

The python script that sends the binary digits:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)
minute = datetime.datetime.now().time().minute
while True:
  second = datetime.datetime.now().time().second
  second_bin = bin(second)[2:].zfill(6) #make sure every string of digits is the same length
  send_string = ""
  for x in second_bin:
    send_string += (str(x)+"k") #appends a letter after every digit for the arduino parseInt function
  ser.write(send_string.encode())
```

The arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    for(int i=8; i<=13; i++){
      int bit = Serial.parseInt();
      if (bit == 1){
        digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
        } else {
          digitalWrite(i, LOW);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this would be a lot easier to debug if you sent the data across in ascii.  That would let you check both sides easily with a terminal emulator.  Perhaps you're testing for (bit == 1) when you want (bit == '1') ?

Comment: The parseInt function returns an integer so im sure it is == 1 not == "1"

Comment: I could indeed send it through ascii instead of this but now that this problem occured i'm actually really curious what causes it because I really can't find a mistake anywhere.

Comment: Maybe you have timing/sync issues? Possibly the first two numbers arrive while the Arduino isn't listening yet?